# What types of sounds do cars make?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

What words can be used to describe the sound a driving car makes? I'm specifically looking for words that could apply to a standard 2000 Honda Civic, or comparable vehicle.

"Roar" sounds too powerful.

"Whir" sounds like a word you'd use to describe an electric fan.

It'd also be absolutely amazing if the word could be used in place of "roar" in the phrase "the car roared to life."

Comment: Modern cars aren't supposed to make much noise at all. There's the comfort of travellers and the general public near the highway to consider, not to mention the fact that fuel economy implies aerodynamic body shape. At most, what we're looking for is something like "muted hum".

Comment: Well, depending on whether the owner is a teenage boy or a sensible businessman, the phrase could either be "the car purred to life", "the car buzzed to life like a swarm of angry hornets", or "the car trumpeted to life like a room of flatulent Deaf".

Comment: "Cough, rattle, rattle, cough."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Vroom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vroom) is really the specific [onomatopoetic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onomatopoeia) word for the sound of a car starting up. According to some sources it is [cross-linguistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias#Car_engine_revving).

There are many options, though. Depending on connotations desired, in rough mild-to-wild order, "The car [ blank ] to life":

- Came
- Spun (up)
- Cranked
- Whispered
- Purred
- Whirred
- Hummed
- Chortled
- Stuttered
- Sputtered
- Whined
- Coughed
- Buzzed
- Rumbled
- Grumbled
- Growled
- Snarled
- Revved
- Zoomed
- Vroomed
- Screamed
- Roared
- Blasted
- Thundered
- Detonated
- Exploded

My favorite is: The car grumbled to life.

Some of these feel a little awkward, but can be improved by rephrasing, such as "the car came to life with a quiet whine." Or perhaps "When he turned the key, the car briefly chortled, then began to purr."

Comment: I absolutely love this list! Amazing! +1 and accepted.

Comment: Or, if electric: The Prius whispered to life. ;)

Comment: @NathanArthur thank you! May I ask which one you plan to use?

Comment: @Mark Whispered is in the list.

Comment: Missed it. It must have been too quiet.

Answer (score 8):

You may say

> The car [vroomed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vroom) to life.

Answer (score 6):

A *driving* car makes a different sound than a car that is starting up.  A driving car might *[purr](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/purr)* if it's a good car, or *[hum](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hum)* or *[drone](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/drone)*.

If it's starting up, as you  seem to indicate by your example sentence, *[rev](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rev)* or *[roar](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/roar)* fits, though naturally *roar* would only work for some cars.

The onomatopoeic *[vroom](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vroom)* is usually used of a driving car, though as Will Hunting indicates, it's vague enough to be used in describing the car starting.

You're right in that *whir* doesn't fit (or at least is not used to describe) a car's noise.  It may be used to describe its motion, e.g. *the car whirred past and sped down the road*.

For your example sentence, I would say:

> [The car's engine revved to life.](https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS475US475&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS475US475&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20car%27s%20engine%20revved%20to%20life%22&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=49e91e21499bfe9d&ix=seb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1366&bih=643)

Comment: I have heard people say their Prius whirs. :)

Answer (score 2):

Expensive luxury (rather than sports) cars are often described as "purring", although I'm not sure that would quite apply to a Honda Civic :)

Rather than "roaring" to life, a car could perhaps be described as "revving", although it wouldn't normally do that once it was up and running normally.

Answer (score 1):

The question was "...what **types** of sounds..." *not* "...what sounds..."

Therefore, I submit that there are two **types** of sounds: (1) normal, and (2) expensive. Note that Type 1 sounds are completely subsumed within Type 2 sounds if the provenance of the vehicle is Italian.

Comment: Good catch! Perhaps another category could be "Abnormal?" (Backfiring, car without a muffler, the squeal of a belt slipping, etc)